Notation in Johnson, Kotz, and Balakrishnan: $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$
I have before me Continuous Univariate Distributions, Volume 1, Second Edition, by Johnson, Kotz, and Balakrishnan. On page 19 it says:

The tables in Pearson and Hartley (1972) give standardized quantiles (percentiles) of Pearson system distributions to four decimal places for $\sqrt{\beta_1}=0.0(0.1)2.0$ and for $\beta_2$ increasing by intervals of $0.2.$

I can't find any place in the book before that where it says what $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are, but the book relies heavily on that notation in the sequel.
What am I missing?

These ($\beta_1, \beta_2$) are the square of third-moment skewness, and ordinary fourth-moment kurtosis of the distribution in question respectively. You'll most commonly see this in older works.
The notation dates back to Pearson (1895)[1], p 351.

(NB: this paper is long out of copyright. Don't let people charge you for it.)
[While it's not an issue with your particular quote, one thing to watch out for in some books and papers that use these symbols is that some authors use $\sqrt{\beta_1}$ to mean the ordinary (signed) skewness rather than its absolute value. This is really bad - and not just because it fools unaware readers - indeed I have seen some very famous statisticians fool themselves with this, by sometimes forgetting that the quantity they say at one place is signed is not always positive later on. Watch out, this dog bites.]
[1]: Pearson, K. (1895). "X. Contributions to the mathematical theory of evolution.—II. Skew variation in homogeneous material" Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London. A, 186, pp343-414 (+plates). https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.1895.0010  (viewable and downloadable from there)

This seems consistent with this Wikipedia page.

I see an error  not far away on that page, unfortunately.  Note to self, fix the missing $^2$ term in one place.

Yes, as written in the square of.
